# Including pythton dice script in html page

Tags: python-3.x

i created a dice rolling script in python for a roleplaying game I'm playing.

```
import random

# Roll dice, if 6 reroll and remove 6.
def dice_roll():
    value = ((random.randint(1, 6)))
    if value == 6:
        print(value)
        return dice_roll() + dice_roll()
    else:
        print(value)
        return value


def roll_dices():
    # How many dice.
    number_of_dices = int(input("How many dice would you like to roll?" + "\n"))
    print(" ")
    print("\n" + "Dices to roll: " + str(number_of_dices) + "\n")
    final_sum = 0
    i = 1
    while i <= number_of_dices:
        final_sum += dice_roll()
        i += 1
    print("The final sum is: " + str(final_sum))


roll_dices()
```

I've been trying to look for a way for me to use it on a HTML page or as an exe with no success. Any tips on how you could turn the code to something you can run outside of terminal or cmd?

Comment: Maybe you're searching for frameworks like Django, Flask etc. Is that you're wanted?

Comment: Looks like something i should check out! Thanks alot! , Looks like a chose a bad program to write when learning python and should've probably chosen another language.

Comment: Sure translating it to Javascript and including it in a single HTML page seems like the easier choice. Depending on what are your future plans for the game aid tool you're doing ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a small example using `flask`. Just copy the two files somewhere, the `.html` in the `templates/` folder below app.py and then run `python app.py` (assuming you installed flask, otherwise run `pip install flask` beforehand)

app.py
    import os
    from flask import Flask
    from flask import render_template
    import random
    from flask import jsonify

```
app = Flask(__name__)

# Roll dice, if 6 reroll and remove 6.
def dice_roll():
    value = ((random.randint(1, 6)))
    if value == 6:
        print(value)
        return dice_roll() + dice_roll()
    else:
        print(value)
        return value

def roll_dices(number_of_dices):
    # How many dice.
    final_sum = 0
    i = 1
    while i <= number_of_dices:
        final_sum += dice_roll()
        i += 1
    #print("The final sum is: " + str(final_sum))
    return final_sum

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/rollNdice/<int:num>')
def rollDice(num):
    return jsonify({"num":num,"sum":roll_dices(num)})

app.run()
```

template/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="/action_page.php">
         How many dice would you like to roll? <input type="range" id="numDice" value="3" max=6 min=1><br>
         The final sum is:  <p id="sum"></p>
      <button type="button" onclick="getRoll()">Click Me!</button>
    </form>
  </body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      function getRoll() {
          var x = $("#numDice").val();
          $.getJSON( "/rollNdice/"+x, function( data ) {
            document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML  = data["sum"] + " rolling " + data["num"] +" dice</br>"
          });
      }
  </script>
</html>
```

[image: preview]

Looks quite spartan, but I hope it helped :)

Comment: Looks super interesting, At work now so i can unfortunately not download trough python but i will try as soon as i come back home and it's a great example for me to learn from aswell! Thanks alot

Comment: Was the example useful in the end? For simple scripts, just extending the JS in the .html page would definetly be easier. With flask you could develop a backend, with database binding, user sessions... Don't know which way you intended your project to go :) If it solves your problem please mark my answer as correct ^^ Greetings, Paul

Comment: I'm very much a beginner so it feels like the kind of things I create just doing a JS and including on a html seems easier but I think I learned from your example and I think I managed to mark it as correct as well. Thanks again